# TableviewController as detail controller with NSmutable Arrays

Tags: ios, arrays, json

say you have Nsmutable array that gets its data through JSON. This data is displayed on tableview controller which has another tableviewcontroller as detail and another tableviewcontroller as a third detail.

I have declared properties and synthesised the arrays as follows
table1 view controller

```
NSMutableArray *venueData;
NSMutableArray *patientData;

NSMutableArray *moreInfo
```

the second table will drilldown on venues and patient data

The table source receives its data via json as follows

```
AFJSONRequestOperation *operation = [AFJSONRequestOperation JSONRequestOperationWithRequest:request 
                    success:^(NSURLRequest *request, NSHTTPURLResponse *response, id JSON) {


    id results = [JSON valueForKeyPath:@"data"];

    [results enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(id obj, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {
    [self.venueData addObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[obj valueForKey:@"venueInfo"]]];
    [self.patientData addObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[obj valueForKey:@"patientInfo"]]];
    [self.moreData addObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[obj valueForKey:@"moreInfo"]]];

//additional code etc  
}
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    //usual code, uiviewcell subclass, dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier etc

    [[cell venue] setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [venueData objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]]];
    [[cell patient] setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [patientData objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]]];

    return cell;
}
```

next

I am using segue

```
if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"ShowDetails"]) 
{
    NSIndexPath *selectedRowIndex = [self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow];
    SecondViewController *detailViewController = segue.destinationViewController;
    //detailViewController.delegate=self;

    detailViewController.moreInfo=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[moreData objectAtIndex:selectedRowIndex.row]];
}
```

I have created a third array and called it moreInfo, where I am storing moreInfo such as venueDescription, venueLocation etc

such that in `secondViewController`, my row is returned by the content of that array

I am able to receive data on first table, however the detail table displays the same information for all the indexes e.g when you click VenuI or Venue2, you get all the details for venue 1, venue 2, venue 3 etc

Could I get ideas on the best approach

Comment: How do you display the drilled down view controllers ? Can you post some code ?

Comment: @Rajiv, I have edited to include more info